# Generating compact scientific notation with ggplot2 on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

The plots I generate with ggplot2 look like the one on the left with the full scientific notation on each tick of the y axis. How can I get it to look more compact like the plot on the right, which has the scientific notation labeled in the corner as circled in red?

I have not seen this mentioned in the ggplot2 package documentation or on stack overflow. Does anyone have a workaround?

[two formats for scientific notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KBvX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a similar plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg * 1E-8)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

If we know the scale we want to use, we could define it, and then we could either scale the data on the way in, or change the labels on the y axis, will look the same, except for y axis label (which we could rename whatever we want):

```
divisor = 1E-8

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg * 1E-8 / divisor)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = formatC(divisor, format = "e", digits = 0))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg * 1E-8)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x / divisor) +
  labs(title = formatC(divisor, format = "e", digits = 0))
```

[image]

---

Edit:

If you also want a title, you could alternatively use `annotate` to write the text outside the plot area, and then scootch the title up:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg * 1E-8)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x / divisor) +
  annotate("text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 0, vjust = -0.5,
           label = formatC(divisor, format = "e", digits = 0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  labs(title = "Title here") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(0,0,20,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response @Jon Spring. Will this allow me to place a title as well? Looks like the divisor took its place.

Comment: Added another approach that would keep the ability to add a separate title.